# Why GetQueuedCompletionStatus() does not return operation type?

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi, network-programming, overlapped-io

`GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` dequeue a completion notification, but it does not return what type of notification it is (e.g. Read notification, write notification).

It is my responsibility to keep track of what operations I initiate, for example when I use `WSARecv()`, I add a flag to the `OVERLAPPED` structure that indicate what operation this is (read in this case), and when I dequeue a notification, I read this flag. So does anyone knows why `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` does not return the type of operation?

Comment: Because you are supposed to keep track of that yourself.  The pointer you get back is your key.  It is common to derive your own struct from OVERLAPPED to store any additional context.

Comment: Its none of `GQCS`'s business what the operation actually was. That's up to **you**. It should be managed as such (as part of your per-IO state, generally via an extension of the OVERLAPPED structure). IOCP programming for actual IO (you can also use them without IO at all) is very-much a state-machine-style of programming, where **you** manage said-state.

Answer (score 1):

Why should it care? You can pass user data through the APIs that result in a completion being extracted via `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` so why do you need anything else? Since you can post your own completions using `PostQueuedCompletionStatus()` there's an infinite number of 'operations' that you could complete, so pass it in the 'extended `OVERLAPPED` structure and you can pass anything...

If you COULD pass your own separate flag then it wouldn't actually remove the need to pass additional extra stuff as an extended `OVERLAPPED` structure as it's pretty useful to be able to pass the data buffer and other information along with the operation anyway, so one extra flag is unlikely to be worth having... My designs need more than your designs need, so lets just deal with the method that the API designers gave us...